# How to use transform by css3?

Tags: css

```
-webkit-transform: perspective(500) rotateY(13deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 45%;
```

DIV is left side position.

i just want to know how to place it right side(opposite)?

Comment: pls add ur code here or give jsfiddle for the same

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided will produce something that behaves like [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7heqm2uh/).

Typically, the CSS3 transform property is used to rotate, scale, are move an element about a point. To move an element to the right of the page, like what I think you are describing, you should just simply `float` the element to the right or use the `margin` property instead.

```
div {
    float: right;
}
```

[This source](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) discusses all the various CSS3 transform functions. The most common are:

```
translate(x,y)
scale(x,y)
rotate(angle)
skew(x-angle,y-angle)
```

These would not 'move' an element to the right side of the page like you are describing.

Comment: Using `absolute positioning` and `right:xyz px` should do it nicely (iif you wanted to add this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7heqm2uh/1/) to your answer) - i'd not advise using floats as this 'removes' the element from the parent div.